# Ansible Shared Inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm looking for an elegant solution to some form of shared inventory which can be used for variables that persist regardless of the current inventory.

Example: There are multiple inventories used to define environments:

```
/inventory-live/
/inventory-staging/
/inventory-test/
/inventory-develop/
```

Each of these customises a load of environment specific detail. However, some content such as licence keys, user credentials and so are on are not environment specific.

Currently this information is manually kept in sync by updating the `*/group_vars/all` in each inventory.

But is there a more elegant solution that keeps this in a central location and doesn't involve repeating the same information between inventories?

Comment: If you want variables not dependant on the inventory, why don't you use a regular variable-file?

Comment: That is what I've done previously. Over time, I've come to respect that separating configuration into the inventory and tasks into the roles is a good convention. Sticking to conventions makes it easier for others who have to use your work. Hence I'm trying to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use all these inventories with single playbook, you can place `group_vars/all` into your playbook directory – Ansible reads host and groups vars not only from inventory files, but also from current playbook directory.

If you use these inventories with multiple playbooks, you can create common directory and symlinks from different inventories:

```
/inventory-common/common_vars.yml
/inventory-live/group_vars/all/common.yml -> ../../../inventory-common/common_vars.yml
/inventory-test/group_vars/all/common.yml -> ../../../inventory-common/common_vars.yml
```

Comment: That works with group_vars. For some reason, it doesn't work with `/inventory-live/host_vars/localhost/common.yml` The file is not read in that scenario, but `/inventory-live/host_vars/localhost/vars.yml` does work. I can't find any documentation on this behavior (Ansible 2.2), but the provided answer works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in Ansible 2.4 in  https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/8f97aef1a365cbbbb822d6d09f96af17a076b295 is the ability to specify multiple inventory files either on the command line:

`--inventory inventory1 --inventory inventory2`

or ansible.cfg:

`inventory = inventory1,inventory2`

inventory1 would be the shared inventory and matching keys in inventory2 would override inventory1.

source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5316#issuecomment-345051733

Comment: The [inventory generator](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/generator.html) in 2.6 is also a great solution now available.